# Are there any editors for .rmz files created by Outlook for exporting rules

Tags: text-editor, editor

I had posted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1157079/export-only-a-selected-rule-from-outlook) on Superuser asking for ways to export a particular rule from Outlook. So far it looks like there isn't a easy way to do it.
The question did not receive enough attention and hence there is a bounty on it now.
I was wondering if there was an editor for editing the `.rmz` Outlook files (which hold the rules) one could edit this file and keep only the rules that need to be exported.

**Background**: I had created a rule in Outlook and would want all other employees to use it. I wanted to pass this new rule only as an attachment - but it turned out that the exported .rmz file had all my rules.